# Fischer-Speier Esterification: Sulfuric acid removal following creation of ester

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, esters

I'm a beginning chemistry student, and I was wondering what the best way of removing sulfuric acid was following the creation of benzyl acetate. So far, I have that benzyl alcohol and glacial acetic acid are mixed in a 1:1 ratio to create the benzyl acetate in a beaker filled with molecular sieves (to remove the water and shift the reaction to the right). However, I am unsure as to how much sulfuric acid to add and how best to remove it from the final solution of ester, water, and sulfuric acid.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE.  If you accessed a reference stating the molar ratio of alcohol and acetic acid (why not acetanhydride?), likely the same reference will provide you a hint about the catalytic amount of sulfuric acid necessary.  Give you a mid- and longterm favour, narrow your question, and show evidence you read further the lab protocol provided to you.  Or take bus #69 to either Irchel or Hönggerberg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical esterification, the sulfuric acid plays a catalytic role, so you don't need a lot, and removing it should not be a concern. Also, to drive the *equilibrium* reaction forward, you would want a slight excess of one of the reactants, usually the cheaper one of the acid or the alcohol (acetic acid in your particular case). The sulfuric acid is also a good dehydrating agent, so the sieves seem excessive. Finally, the ester is a bit more volatile than the other components (check a handbook for boiling points!), so distillation is standard. Otherwise, look into a [Dean-Stark trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean%E2%80%93Stark_apparatus).

For other ideas on how one usually conducts an esterification, look up related syntheses in *Organic Synthesis*; e.g. [this one](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0264) or [this one](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0365) or [this one](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0414).

Answer (score 0):

Catalytic sulfuric acid is required so just a few drops should do it.
To remove (or as it normally expressed work up) dilute the mixture with a relatively low boiling point  organic solvent - ethyl acetate is good - and wash the solution with dil. sodium hydrogen carbonate solution. Separate off the organic phase (upper phase if you used EtOAc), dry it with a solid drying agent such as anhydrous magnesium sulfate, filter and remove the solvent under reduced pressure.

Comment: If the use of acetic acid/H2SO4 isn't mandatory, why not use acetic anhydride?